# Associate a requirement with a release in ALm using C#

Tags: c#, qtp, alm

I want to associate a requirement with a release in ALm using C#.

I have tried this code but I get an error . First I read to old release then I tried to copy it but I get an error.

```
foreach (Release rl in listRel)
if (rl.Name == ReleasetreeView.SelectedNode.Name)
{

NewORL = rl;
sif = NewORL.ScopeItemFactory;
altsif = ORL.ScopeItemFactory;

NewORL.Post();

foreach (ScopeItem si in altsif.NewList(""))
{

RMSI = sif.AddItem(System.DBNull.Value);
RMSI.Name = si.Name;
RMSI.Priority = si.Priority;
RMSI.AutoPost = si.AutoPost;
RMSI.Description = si.Description;
RMSI.Post();
CDF = RMSI.ContentDefinitionFactory;
altCDF = si.ContentDefinitionFactory;
ContentPartFactory cpf,ncpf;
ContentRootFactory crf,ncrf;

foreach (ContentDefinition CD in altCDF.NewList(""))
{
string s=CD.Name;
cpf = CD.ContentPartFactory;

crf = CD.ContentRootFactory;
ncrf = CD.ContentRootFactory;
foreach (ContentRoot CR in crf.NewList(""))
{


ContentRoot = ncrf.AddItem(System.DBNull.Value);
ContentRoot.Name = CR.Name;
ContentRoot.RootEntityId = CR.RootEntityId;
ContentRoot.RootEntityType = CR.RootEntityType;


 ContentRoot.Post();


}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, please post a code sample that will run on its own.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Failed to Post Simple Key Entity'
i am trying to copy release with it's associate  requirement using c# .i have copied alle Cyles and ScopeItem but i didn#t found out how to copy the associate  requirement fron old release to new one .thanks alot im advance for your help .

Answer (score 0):

i have found my fehler

```
 //Copy New ContentDefinition from selected ContentDefinition
            var CDF = RMSI.ContentDefinitionFactory;
            var altCDF = si.ContentDefinitionFactory;

            foreach (ContentDefinition CD in altCDF.NewList(""))
            {
                CDFF= CDF.AddItem(System.DBNull.Value);
                CDFF.Name = CD.Name;
                CDFF.AutoCompleteType = CD.AutoCompleteType;
                CDFF.Post();

                //Copy New ContentRoot from selected ContentRoot
                //ContentRoot is requirement
                var crf = CD.ContentRootFactory;
                var ncrf = CDFF.ContentRootFactory;


                foreach (ContentRoot CR in crf.NewList(""))
                {

                    //Add associate a requirement
                    var ContentRoot = ncrf.AddItem(System.DBNull.Value);
                    ContentRoot.Name = CR.Name;
                    ContentRoot.RootEntityId = CR.RootEntityId;
                    ContentRoot.RootEntityType = CR.RootEntityType;
                    ContentRoot.Post();



                }
            }
```